# Is the magnitude of a vector equal to its length

Tags: vectors, definition, measurements, units

Suppose a body has a velocity  $V =2\hat i$ metres per second. The magnitude of velocity is 2 meters per second . We can draw a vector of length 2 cm to represent this velocity.
According to the below source, the magnitude of the vector should be equal to its length which is 2 cm. Which is incorrect.

What then does the length of the vector convey to us in physics?

https://mathinsight.org/definition/magnitude_vector

Comment: The "length" of a vector (aka its "magnitude") has the same units of the vector (in this case m/s). It is a math operation  ( the "Euclidean norm" of a vector), not something related to how you arbitrarily choose to draw things on paper.

Comment: TLDR: They're not just equal. "Length" and "magnitude" literally mean the same thing when we're talking about vectors. "Magnitude" is more formal, but "length" is intuitive when we're talking (or just thinking) about vectors that are represented by arrows in a diagram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we talk about the length of a vector, we mean the length of the quantity it represents, not the length of the drawing on paper. The length is calculated, rather than measured. Sometimes, if the vector represents a position or displacement and the lengths are small enough to draw on a piece of paper, then the length can be measured with a ruler.

But, most of the time, a drawing of a vector is only a representation of a vector, much like a stick figure can represent a person. This is especially true when the vector quantity is a velocity, acceleration, force, electric field, or any other quantity which is not a length. In these cases, the "length" of this vector is no longer something you could measure with a ruler, but is rather the total magnitude or strength or amount of the vector that ignores any sense of direction.

Your vector might represent a car going 2 m/s to the east (if $\hat{j}$ is north and $\hat{i}$ is east). The length of this vector is speed of the car: 2 m/s. Notice that direction drops out. Also notice that the length of a vector has the same units as the original vector: m/s.

Comment: So basically there is a scale we use. Say one cm means a velocity of 1m/a & so on?

Comment: @Kashmiri Sure. Although I never spend much time drawing vectors exactly right when doing physics. I spend most time with the numbers after drawing a quick sketch.

Comment: Thank you. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3):

It is essential to avoid confusion between a physical quantity and its graphical representation.

The vector character of a physical quantity cannot be judged by looking for arrows in the real world. Nobody sees velocity, a force, or an electric field. The vector character of those quantities is revealed by the fact that these quantities can be summed, scaled, and these operations have specific rules.

Once one knows that a physical quantity is a vector, it is possible to *represent* it using arrows (oriented segments) in the three-dimensional space. The representation allows to translate and represent physical properties in terms of the geometrical properties of the arrows. Thus, the intensity of a physical vector can be *represented* by the "intensity" of an arrow, which turns out to be nothing but its geometrical length. Of course, the representation is usually based on a change of physical dimensions, and the intensity of the vector has not to be dimensionally homogeneous to a length. But this should not be a surprise. Even for non-vector quantities, we routinely use such a change of units. Think, for example, of the plot of temperature vs time. We dimensionally rescale values of time and temperature to distances along a line.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the magnitude of a vector equal to its length ?

Not necessarily. Every vector has a magnitude, but only some vectors have a length.

A [Euclidean vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector) (sometimes called a geometric vector or a spatial vector) has a length - the distance between its two ends - which is equal to its magnitude.

However, vectors in other non-geometric vector spaces - such as velocity vectors - do not have a length. Sometimes, by analogy with Euclidean vectors, the magnitude of a non-Euclidean vector may be referred to informally as its "length", but strictly speaking this is incorrect.

So in your example the velocity vector has a magnitude of 2 metres per second, but has no length, whereas the Euclidean vector has a magnitude of 2 cm, which is also its length.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that one use of the word *length* when associated with the word *magnitude* of a vector is as an aide-mémoire to remind one that magnitude can only be a positive quantity as a length is always positive particularly when using the word *component*.

Another use is to help with the visualisation of a vector which in general is an abstract entity.
When drawn either on paper or the imagination, the length of the vector is associated with a scale which converts the length of the "drawn" vector to the magnitude of the entity being described as a vector.

The confusion shown by the OP is because the author of the quoted passage is using the words *length* and *magnitude* interchangeably going from the abstract *magnitude* to the graphical representation *length* as though the words were synonyms which was probably done for brevity.

Answer (score 1):

You make a scale for the representation on paper according to your convenience- say, you state that 1 cm on paper is equal to 1 m/s of speed. That way, you can represent 2 m/s as a vector of length 2 cm, and 1 m/s of as a vector of length 1 cm. You can change the scale on paper as you want, but you have to make sure that doubling, tripling, etc. the magnitude will double, triple, etc. respectively the length of the line/arrow representing that vector quantity.